# increase List threshold or Custom Filter?

Tags: web-part, list, filter, list-view-threshold

I have a list over 200,000 items in it. It's on normal threshold (2,000 items per view). Users want large threshold but there is price for that. SQL traveling/transaction, server overhead and the whole nine yard.

Is there a codeplex or custom filter option webpart that can be place in the list view page so that users can use the custom filter to type in whatever they are looking for instead of list's built in filter options?

I hope I am making sense.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like search might be a good option. Maybe create a special search page (could be the view page) where you:

- Add a search box
- Add a core results web part where you:

  - set site:UrlOfList as additional query parameters
  - set xslt to render with the information you want

And then teach users about Keyword query syntax

Answer (score 0):

For that, I'd say create a view with the desired columns then use the Export to Spreadsheet option.  Save the IQY file generated to a Document library or a datasource library and  point the user to it.  They can then open that in Excel and do all the filtering on their local machine and not pound the server.

The opening of the IQY file will pull down all the data, regardless of what the list view paging options are set at.

Or the user could open Access and pull down a copy of the list and query it that way.  I prefer the Excel option personally.